# Ambiguous type array is NOT recommended

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

When running PHP Code sniffer with the Magento 2 standard included in the dev tools on my code I receive the `Ambiguous type array is NOT recommended` warning quite frequently, is there a way to solve the warning?

`php vendor/bin/phpcs --warning-severity=1 \
--standard=dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/_files/phpcs/ruleset.xml \
-d memory_limit=1024M --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php,phtml \
vendor/vendorName/moduleName/`

> FOUND 0 ERROR(S) AND 3 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 3 LINE(S)
>
> - 24 | WARNING | Ambiguous type "array" for @var is NOT recommended
> - 42 | WARNING | Ambiguous type "array" for @return is NOT recommended
> - 63 | WARNING | Ambiguous type "array" for @return is NOT recommended

Answer (score 1):

Entirely depends on context. The preferred solution would be one of two things (or possibly a combination of both):

1. If your array is a set of values all having consistent type, specify that sub-type explicitly. For instance, if you have a `$param` array of `\My\Class\Model\Something` instances, rather than `array $param`, your type definition should be `\My\Class\Model\Something[] $param`.
2. If your array is not a set of consistent type, but always follows the same pattern (it should!), convert it into an object with a defined interface.

For #2: Say you have an array to hold multiple values for the response:

```
$response = [
    'message' => 'Success',
    'error' => false,
];
return $response;
```

Rather than returning this array (type `array`), you should turn that into an object:

```
class Response extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject implements ResponseInterface
{
    public function setMessage(string $message)
    {
        return $this->setData('message', $message);
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->getData('message');
    }

    public function setError(bool $error)
    {
        return $this->setData('error', $error);
    }

    public function getError()
    {
        return $this->getData('error');
    }
}
```

And then use dependency injection to inject a `ResponseFactory` (as `$this->responseFactory`), then:

```
$response = $this->responseFactory->create();
$response->setMessage('Success');
$response->setError(false);
return $response;
```

And suddenly you have a defined interface, and every bit of code knows that response is going to be an instance of `Response`, with a message and an error flag, as well as the types of each, and how to get to them.

By defining types, you remove ambiguity and the possibility of anomalous behavior.